# Configure system proxy in GNUStep to be used by NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am using Objective C in GNUStep 1.24 with clang 3.4 on Windows 7

From behind our corporate (authenticated) proxy, I'm trying to make a simple NSURLConnection (NSURL->NSURLRequest->NSURLConnection) over HTTP.

However this only results in "Host not found using 'gethostbyname()'". Clearly I need to specify the HTTP proxy information.

What I have tried:

1. My understanding (according to cocoa spec) is that NSURLConnection should use the system proxy settings, so I am assuming that it is not set. However, I have not been able to find GNUStep documentation on how to set this.
2. SystemConfiguration API does not seem to be available with GNUStep, so I could not investigate this programmatically.
3. By setting the relevant proxy configuration in the GNUStep shell, I can use e.g. wget without issue. I also tried setting this in the windows environment variable just in case.
4. I know that by implementing a NSURLProtocol I could implement my own proxy, but this seems a bit advanced for my needs (and skill).
5. I know of the availability of other networking libraries, such as AFNetworking, which I have not investigated yet as I would like to address the basic problem.

Does anyone know how to set the system HTTP proxy for GNUStep such that I will be used by NSURLConnection? Otherwise, if I have misunderstood the situation, what should I be doing in this situation?

Further: Ultimately I will need to make these requests over HTTPS using both host and client certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether GNUstep's sources include support for the system wide proxy configuration. But maybe you can find out yourself when looking at the sources: http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSURLConnection.m

If that feature is missing, please file a bug report here: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=gnustep or send a mail to bug-gnustep@gnu.org

Comment: This should've been a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I was not familiar with the subtle differences between comments and answers.